# json schema element optional depending on other element value

Tags: json, jsonschema

below is my json schema

I have a dependency where all optional tag mentioned should be true only if actionType element value id "SAVECONTACT"

i dont know how to implement such dependency

please help me out with this

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "userId": {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true
        },
        "groupId": {
            "type": "string",
            "optional": true
        },
        "socialMediaContacts": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "smContactId": {
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    "actionType": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "enum" : ["SAVECONTACT", "DELETECONTACT", "SAVEGROUP", "DELETEGROUP"]
                    },
                    "contactLastName": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "contactFirstName": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "nickName": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "contactType": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "enum" : ["SM", "REG"],
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "mediaSource": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "enum" : ["FB", "FS", "TW"],
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "socialMediaHandle": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "email": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "optional": true
                    },
                    "phone": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "optional": true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle this kind of situation, you probably need `"oneOf"`.

Basically, you create a schema for each situation - "SAVECONTACT", and non-"SAVECONTACT":

```
{
    "type": "object",
    ... /* other constraints */
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "actionType": {"enum": ["SAVECONTACT"]}
            },
            "required": [... all the properties ...]
        }
        {
            "properties": {
                "actionType": {"enum": ["DELETECONTACT", ...]}
            },
            "required": [/* empty */]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem might be using the same approach [that suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18384131/2660176).

First, I would use the standard way to use "required" instead of your custom tag "optional". Then something like this could work if you have a Draft 4 validator:

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "userId": {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true
    },
    "groupId": {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true
    },
    "socialMediaContacts": {
        "type": "array",
        "allOf":
        {
            "properties": {
                    "smContactId": {"type":"string"},
                    "actionType": {"enum" : ["SAVECONTACT", "DELETECONTACT", "SAVEGROUP", "DELETEGROUP"]},
                    "contactLastName": {"type":"string"},
                    "contactFirstName": {"type":"string"},
                    "nickName": {"type":"string"},
                    "contactType": {"type":"string","enum" : ["SM", "REG"]},
                    "mediaSource": {"type":"string","enum" : ["FB", "FS", "TW"]},
                    "socialMediaHandle": {"type":"string"},
                    "email": {"type":"string"},
                    "phone": {"type":"string"}
                },
                "required": ["actionType","smContactId"],
                "additionalProperties": False
            },
        "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/savecontact" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/otheroperations" }
        ]
    }
},
"definitions": {
    "savecontact": {
        "properties": {
            "actionType": { "enum": [ "SAVECONTACT" ] },

        },
        "required": ["contactLastName","contactFirstName", etc. etc.],
    },
    "otheroperations": {
        properties": {
            "actionType": {"enum" : ["DELETECONTACT", "SAVEGROUP", "DELETEGROUP"]}
        }
    }
}
```

}

I don't know the full context of your problem, but perhaps to have one schema per operation might have more sense.