# How to use definitions in JSON schema (draft-04)

Tags: json, jsonschema

The rest service response I am working with is similar to following example, I have only included 3 fields here but there are many more:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "Person",
            "name": "Mr Bean",
            "dateOfBirth": "14 Dec 1981"
        },
        {
            "type": "Company",
            "name": "Pi",
            "tradingName": "Pi Engineering Limited"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a JSON schema file for above (draft-04) which will explicitly specify that:

```
if type == Person then list of required properties is ["type", "name", "dateOfBirth", etc] 
OR
if type == "Company" then list of required properties is ["type", "name", "tradingName", etc]
```

However am unable to find any documentation or example of how to do it.

Currently my JSON schema looks like following:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["results" ],
    "properties": {
        "results": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": ["type", "name"],
                "properties": {
                    "type": { "type": "string" },
                    "name": { "type": "string" },
                    "dateOfBirth": { "type": "string" },
                    "tradingName": { "type": "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers/examples of how I should handle this.

Comment: I think you should describe this with an inheritance: Type Person extends MyObject, type Company extends MyObject, and in your main schema define an array with items of type MyObject

Comment: Don't know how similar JSONSchema is to XSD's, but from what I can remember about XSD you don't need a common superclass for your object. You would rather your inheritance within the schemafiles. E.g an abstract placeholder in your main schema, which would allow the person schema and company schema to take its place.

Comment: I see dependencies is also in draf 3. Cany anyone explain any differences with regard to dependencies between draft 3 and 4?

Comment: I don't think Mr. Bean was born 14th Dec '81.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the recommended approach is the one shown in [Json-Schema web, Example2](http://json-schema.org/example2.html). You need to use an enum to select schemas "by value". In your case it would be something like:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [ "results" ],
    "properties": {
        "results": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/person" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/company" }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "person": {
            "properties": {
                "type": { "enum": [ "person" ] },
                "name": {"type": "string" },
                "dateOfBirth": {"type":"string"}
            },
            "required": [ "type", "name", "dateOfBirth" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "company": {
            "properties": {
                "type": { "enum": [ "company" ] },
                . . . 
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you use instead of oneOf if you only know that content of the results array property are some unknown sub types of, says, "Party" ? related question posted here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416873/how-to-tell-json-schema-validator-to-pick-schema-from-property-value :)

Answer (score 10):

Sorry,

I don't get the point. The question is about the 'dependencies' keyword which is part of the last JSON Schema specification, right?

I do not find 'dependencies' in the accepted answer (?)

It is briefly explained in the last draft.
But http://usingjsonschema.com explained both property and definition dependencies in the book:

http://usingjsonschema.com/assets/UsingJsonSchema_20140814.pdf

start at page 29 (see, explained at page 30)

```
"dependencies": {
     "shipTo":["shipAddress"],
     "loyaltyId":["loyaltyBonus"]
}
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Using **dependencies** is it possible to achieve the above use case.  [Question-click please] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830827/conditional-json-schema-validation-based-on-property-value) . Is it possible to make the field required based on the value of another property. It would be great if you could answer the question in the link.  Thanks, Harry.

Comment: @Harry Do I really need to? The answer some minutes after you asked by "Jason" is perfect ! (see your question)

Comment: @SebastianLasse, perhaps the title is confusing, but please read the original question text after `which will explicitly specify that` and you will find that the answer solves the question requirements. The question is not related to the use of json-schema `dependencies` keyword really. Feel free to improve the title.