# JSON Schema in JSON

Tags: xml, json, xsd, jsonschema

I have a JSON object:

```
{
    "name" : "car",
    "color" : "blue"
}
```

And a JSON Schema which is used to validate it (not specified here).

XML allows you to include a reference to an extern XML Schema Definition for validation in the XML document itself via "xsi:schemaLocation" (the namespace prefix might be different).

Is there an equivalent way to include a reference to a JSON Schema in a JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link from data to a schema describing it is generally considered "metadata", so usually isn't in the data itself.

If you're working over HTTP, you can:

- use a "profile=" parameter in the Content-Type header, or
- use a "Link:" header, with `rel="describedby"` to link to the schema.

The second option is preferable.

If you're loading from a file, or something else, then it's not defined.  Within your own application, you are perfectly free to define something like `"$schema"` to reference schemas.  Although other tools wouldn't pick up on this automatically, it would be obvious to any other developers what you were doing.

Comment: [Json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor33) says if a MIME type is present in the header it's RECOMMENDED to add a profile with URI to schema as value to the Content-Type header. Anything wrong with adding both, Link and profile?

Comment: Not that I can see, although some tools might add the schema twice (or whatever), which could result in duplicate links etc.

Comment: What is your intention to say the `Link:` way is preferable over the `Content-Type` way?

Comment: It allows you to specify multiple schemas if you want (unlike Content-Type), it's consistent with the way you [use a schema to dynamically specify schemas from within data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416873/how-to-tell-json-schema-validator-to-pick-schema-from-property-value/19425639#19425639), more transports/formats I've encountered include link-definitions than Content-Type, and I personally feel it's more elegant. :p