# Is it possible to inline JSON schemas into a JSON document?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Say I defined a data model in JSON. Is it possible to inline a piece of schema definition to this JSON document in order to validate some of the child elements in it?

Edit:

I found [How to tell JSON schema validator to pick schema from property value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416873/how-to-tell-json-schema-validator-to-pick-schema-from-property-value) gave a solution to my question.

Comment: If you use a `describedby` link (that points to inside the data itself) it expresses what you want - but you'd need to make sure your validator supports that.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint. Use this as keyword search I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416873/how-to-tell-json-schema-validator-to-pick-schema-from-property-value basically had answered the same question I had. So I would mark this as a duplicate to this one.