# JSON Schema + JSON Editor: Table with togglable columns

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I'm using JSON Schema (http://json-schema.org/) and jdorn's JSON Editor (https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) for a project, and I can't quite figure out if a particular functionality is supported or not.

Basically, I'm trying to get a tabular input, which is working well based on an array with `format: "table"` . However, I'm also trying to make some of those columns to be toggled (displayed or not) based on another input.

So for example, either a series of boolean properties or a unique enum array would results in something like "Show column B? Yes/No, Show column C? Yes/No?, etc...", and as the user toggled those inputs, the columns in the table would change.

JSON Editor documentation details how to make the *value* of one field depend on another, but not the availability of that field. It makes a passing reference to JSON Schema's `dependencies` property, which looks promising, but I find JSON Schema's documentation to be even more difficult to use.

So, does anyone know if this is supported functionality, either through pure JSON Schema, or through a JSON Editor extension?

Answer (score 2):

In Json-Schema Draft v4 you can define [schema validation dependencies through enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04/18384131#18384131).

But Json-Schema does not presume any UI behaviour from its specification. This is just custom interpretation of the schema in order to build UIs. Json-editor makes its own decisions of how to interpret the schema so you need to analyze if it covers all your needs. Anyway [There is an example where the form is changed when toggling a combo box](http://rawgit.com/jdorn/json-editor/master/examples/advanced.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of the `oneOf` feature, and knew I could use that; However, as far as I can tell, it would require creating a variation on the schema for each of the 2^N possible combinations of columns (and having the user scroll through these to select the combination). If there is no option for making individual properties dependent on other values, I guess I'll eventually go this route.

Comment: Why 2^N? That depends on how many of those combinations are reasonable in your domain. You should need N schemas, one for each option you want to provide. Anyway we migth be stretching json-schema too much. Its purpose is not visualization...

Comment: 2^N because as the question mentioned, what I want is to specify (e.g. based on the value of N named booleans) that each of N properties should be required or not within the schema of some object. In my case, N is 4, so I may do that... so do you know how the `dependencies` feature is supposed to work?

Comment: I still think you need just 4 subschemas that are triggered depending of an enum value (treat the boolean as enums). See if this can work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04/18384131#18384131