# json-schema v4 how-to implements enums depending on enums?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

Using [json-editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor), and looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04/18384131#18384131), I am trying to do the following, using json-schema v4:

Use a root property to select one of two categories `['clothing', 'accessory']`, which will determine enum-values for a `material` property.

The case I am trying to solve has multiple enum-properties depending on the `category`-value.

Pseudocode example:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "Title": "Products",
    "definitions": {
        "clothing": {
            "materials": ["yak", "merino"]
        },
        "accessories": {
            "materials": ["brass", "silver"]
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "productType": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "clothing",
                "accessories"
            ]
        },
        "materials": {
            "type": "array",
            "title": "Materials",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "title": "Material",
                "enum": [
                    {"$ref" : "#definitions/{{productType}}/materials"}
                ]
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions on how to structure this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case it might be easier to define types for the first level with a `oneOf` clause, and use enums just in the nested level. Something like:

```
"definitions" : {
    "materialType" : {
        "oneOf" : [{
                "$ref" : "#definitions/clothing"
            }, {
                "$ref" : "#definitions/accesories"
            }
        ]
    },
    "clothing" : {
        "materials" : {
            "enum" : ["yak", "merino"]
        }
    },
    "accessories" : {
        "materials" : ["enum" : ["brass", "silver"]]
    }
}
```

Then you consume `materialType` like this:

```
"materials": {"$ref":"#definitions/materialType"}
```

If you want also to encode the `materialType` within the object instance, then you may add another property enum like this, but I would not recommend this:

```
"clothing" : {
    "materials" : {
        "enum" : ["yak", "merino"]
    },
    "kind": {"enum" : ["clothing"]}
}
```

Comment: Nice,  but the main problem is that I have multiple enums depending on the category.  So in addition to the material,  there will be a subcategory, e.g. ["ring",  "necklace"]  for accessory,  and ["scarf", "beanie"] for clothing. So would I duplicate the schemas in the "oneOf"s,  so to speak,  or try to access the enum values more directly,  perhaps dynamically? (oh,  and thanks for the answer)

Comment: You may add the enum values to the dependent schemas, such as: "clothing": {"materials":{"enum":["yak",merino"]},"subcategory":{"enum":["ring","necklace"]},"accesory":{"enum":["scarf","beanie"]}} but you are starting to push the limits of json-schema, which validates structure, not data. Another simpler option would be to make data validation as a service extension (in code).That will also simplify your json-schema lifecycle management.

Comment: If Json Schema only validates structure, not data, then the enum type itself clearly falls outside that boundary.  Either you'd have to take enum out and leave it be array, or, provide a way to DRY out enums.

Comment: I see enum more like a constraint on types of values, such as number, string, object, array... enum = "collection of listed items".

Comment: Do not understand the "Then you consume materialType like this:" step... how to implement this in the pseudo code example?