# JSON schema - how to specify permutations of required properties

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

Below is an extract from my JSON schema.

I want to specify that both `algorithm` and `results` are required.

Additionally I want to specify:

- when `algorithm` is `algorithm1`, then results must be one of `results1`, `results2`, or `results3`.
- when `algorithm` is `algorithm2`, then results must be one of `results2`, `results3`, or `results4`.

Is this possible?

```
        "algorithm": {
            "description": "description...",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "",
                "algorithm1",
                "algorithm2"
            ]
        },
        "results": {
            "description": "description...",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "",
                "results1",
                "results2",
                "results3",
                "results4"
            ]
        },
     "required": ["algorithm", "results"]
```

Comment: Enforcing schemas depending on enum values can be done as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04/18384131#18384131

Comment: Thanks @jruizaranguren. I was able to figure it out from your helpful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the reference above from @jruizaranguren, I was able to figure it out.

```
"required": ["results"],
"results": {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/Results1" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/Results2" }
    ]
},
"definitions": {
    "Results1": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["algorithm", "results"],
        "properties": {
            "algorithm": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [ "algorithm1" ]
            },
            "results": {
                "type": "string",
                "allOf": [
                    { "result": "results1" },
                    { "result": "results2" },
                    { "result": "results3" }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Results2": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["algorithm", "results"],
        "properties": {
            "algorithm": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [ "algorithm2" ]
            },
            "results": {
                "type": "string",
                "allOf": [
                    { "result": "results2" },
                    { "result": "results3" },
                    { "result": "results4" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```