# JSON schema for payloads accepted vs objects returned

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm fleshing out schemas for a RESTful web service, and I'm a bit stumped on one small thing. Imagine if I have the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["name"],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "urn": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Since the URN is generated by my service, I don't want to accept it in the client request. So `urn` is not included in the `required` array. However, it IS required in the response, so I can't use this schema to validate the response my service gives. I'd prefer not to have to use two different schemas and have to keep them in sync.

Is there a way to use a single schema to strictly model both cases? Or, if I need to use two schemas, is there a way to reference a common structural schema and just override the `required` field from my request and response schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem and there is no good way to handle it.

The only way to keep it to one schema is to not include the server generated properties in the `required` array and do additional checks on the server side to validate those properties.

No, there is no way to override a schema keyword.  JSON Schema keywords always adds constraints to the set.  You need to start with the common schema and extend from there using `allOf`.

Here is an example of the kind of thing you will need to do.

Creation Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com/create-my-schema",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["name"]
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Full Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com/my-schema",
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "http://example.com/create-my-schema" }],
  "required": ["urn"],
  "properties": {
    "urn": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't care about the human readability of the schemas, this approach is fine.  Otherwise, some people have opted to dynamically build schemas on the server-side so the resulting schemas may have duplication, but the code doesn't.

Comment: It's not ideal, certainly, but I think I can work with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic schema with the use of "**oneOf**"

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "required" : ["name"],
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {
            "oneOf" : [{
                    "$ref" : "#/definitions/withURN"
                }, {
                    "$ref" : "#/definitions/withoutURN"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "definitions" : {
        "withURN" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                },
                "urn" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "withoutURN" : {
            "properties" : {
                "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for some example have a look: http://json-schema.org/example2.html

also this discussion thread: [How to use dependencies in JSON schema (draft-04)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04)

Comment: This looks like it's going to validate both `{"name": "foo", "urn": "bar"}` in any context, which isn't what I want; just using the schema with both properties will already do that. I want two schemas that differ only in the value of the `required` field without having to copy/paste the two schemas.