# Conditional Json Schema validation based on property value

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I have the input json like below,

```js
{
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "testA": "testAValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

the condition is, if value of 'name' is 'A', then 'testA' should be the required field and if value of 'name' is 'B', then 'testB' should be the required field.

This is the Json Schema I tried and its not working as expected,

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "results"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "results": {
      "type": "array",
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/person"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/company"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "testA"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "A"
          ]
        },
        "testA": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "company": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "testB"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "B"
          ]
        },
        "testB": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tried with *"dependecies"* in JSON Schema too but wasn't able to find the correct solution.

Any help / workaround with Sample JSON Schema to achieve the above use case is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dependencies in JSON schema (draft-04)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your're close.  Your `oneOf` needs to be in the `items` keyword.

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/person" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/company" }
        ]
    }
}
```