# How to use oneOf in JSON schema to validate both POST and PATCH requests?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Currently we are using a schema file that contains **oneOf** with 2 schemas: one for PATCH requests and one for POST requests. In Java code we check if id is available in the request then we check if there is any error message for the first schema in oneOf section.

Something like this:

```
        processingReport.iterator().forEachRemaining(processingMessage -> {
        JsonNode json = processingMessage.asJson();

        JSONObject reports = new JSONObject(json.get("reports").toString());
        logger.debug("Schema validation: {}", reports.toString());
        //Seems always has 2 reports.
        String reportIdentifier = isCreate ? "/properties/data/oneOf/0" : "/properties/data/oneOf/1";
        JSONArray errorsArray = new JSONArray(reports.get(reportIdentifier).toString());

        //Do something with the error here

    });
```

But this seems not right to me. Is there any way to manage this in the schema itself so when id is available then it picks the right schema from the oneOf or perhaps there is better way to do it?

I know one option would be having different json files but our technical managers would rather to keep them in 1 place.

Comment: Do you mean to select a schema based on a value included in a property? Then look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375506/how-to-use-dependencies-in-json-schema-draft-04/18384131#18384131

Comment: @jruizaranguren That select the schema from the type but my scenario is different. In my case, the type is the same. (let's say it's always Company) but what schema to select depends on whether property 'id' is available or not. I thought about 'dependencies' but with that you can only say check property x when y is presented. How can we use 'dependencies' to say pick this schema when id is presented? Can you give me an example is that's possible? JSON schema is a bit hard for me to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oneOf` and `anyOf` clauses can be used to model conditional constraints. The following schema would validate on of patch or post schemas depending on the existence of `id` property:

```
{
    "oneOf" : [{
            "$ref" : "/post_request_schema#"
        }, {
            "allOf" : [{
                    "$ref" : "/patch_request_schema#"
                }, {
                    "required" : ["id"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```